# How to delete an image from the database and folder in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, unlink

I have PHP code that I am trying to delete the image from the database and uploads folder as well. I have researched and it seems 
like I need the unlink option but I don't know enough about PHP or 
coding on how to implement it. The code I have will delete from the 
MySQL database just fine but when I try to add the uplink code it 
breaks it and doesn't do anything.

I have tried adding in the following:

```
$file_path = 'uploads/' . $_POST["images"];
if(unlink($file_path))
```

to the code below.

```
        //start PHP session
    session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['success']))
{
    header("Location: login_page.php");
    die();
}

// check if value was posted
if($_POST){

    // include database and object file
    include_once 'config/database.php';

    $file_path = 'uploads/' . $_POST["image"];
    if(unlink($file_path))
 {
    // delete query
    $query = "DELETE FROM dhospital WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['object_id']);
 }
    if($stmt->execute()){
        // redirect to read records page and 
        // tell the user record was deleted
        echo "Record was deleted.";
    }else{
        echo "Unable to delete record.";
    }
}
```

I am using PHP - PDO - MySQL

Comment: You're missing the `{` for your if statement. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Check your $file_path is correct or not . Codes don't seem weird.

Comment: I updated the code above to the full code for my delete.php file. When i add the unlink section it doesn't do anything. If i take that part out it will delete from DB fine.

Comment: i checked the file_path and the uploads is the correct folder they are in and "image" is the name of the database column that holds the name of the image.